# How to set the path for the velocity log file?

Tags: java, velocity

How to set the path for the velocity log file?

I upgraded from velocity-engine 1.7 to 2.3 and velocity-tools 2.0 to 3.1.

The code for setting the path was the following:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty("runtime.log", logPath + "velocity.log");
```

But with the upgrade it does not work anymore. I searched the docs but didn't find anything helpful so far. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity 2.x uses the slf4j logging API. It means that you have to put in the classpath one of the available slf4j implementations :

- [slf4j-simple](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/simple/SimpleLogger.html) that will log by default to `System.err`, you can configure the output file with the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile` system property
- [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/), a full fledged logger similar to log4j configurable with a `logback.xml` and which will allow advanced features like log files rotation
- [webapp-slf4j-logger](https://github.com/arkanovicz/webapp-slf4j-logger) that will redirect log towards the J2EE container logger in the context of a J2EE webapp
- several others around...

Libraries using slf4j cannot be aware themselves of what happens to logged messages, this decoupling has proven to be quite an improvement and has contributed to the success of the slf4j logging library.